# Get the total file size of the number of elements available in the azure blob storage

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure

I'm trying to get the total size of the files available for each user inside the container. I'm using the `map` function to iterate and when I try to console log the value it displays them correctly, but it gives 0 after the map function completed. Any help would be appreciated.

```
const connString: string = process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING!;

const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(
  connString
);

const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient("mycontainer");
```

```
 try {
      let userId = req.params["user_id"];
      let storageInfo: any = await AddToHiveModel.find({ user_id: userId });
      let storageInfoTotal: number = 0;

      console.log(storageInfo.length);
      await AddToHiveModel.find({ user_id: userId }).then((result:any)=> {
        if(result.length > 0){
          result.map( async (element: any) => {
            let blobName = `uploads/${element.user_id}/${element.filename}`;
            await containerClient.getBlobClient(blobName).getProperties()
              .then(
                (result: any) => {
                  storageInfoTotal += Number(result.contentLength);
                })
              .catch((err: any) => {
                return err;
              });
            
            return null;
  
          }
          );
          console.log(storageInfoTotal);
          resp.json(storageInfoTotal);
        }else {
          resp.json(storageInfoTotal);
        }
      });

    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Caught error", err);
      resp.status(500).send(err);
      resp.end();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try fetching the blob's properties.

```php
var blob = _container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
if (blob.Exists())
{
    blob.FetchAttributes();
    return blob.Properties.Length;
}

throw new Exception("Blob doesn't exist");
```

Try this code which can be used to determine the size of the blob:

```css
val blob: CloudBlockBlob = container.getBlockBlobReference(blobPath)
blob.downloadAttributes()
blob.getProperties.getLength
```

To avoid the properties being empty, make sure to call downloadAttributes.

**References:**

1. [Calculate blob count and total size per container using Azure Storage inventory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/calculate-blob-count-size)
2. [Calculate the size/capacity of storage account and it services](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/calculate-the-size-capacity-of-storage-account-and-it-services/ba-p/1064046)
3. [CloudBlockBlob Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob?view=azure-java-legacy)